# Spherical coordinate system

Tags: coordinate-systems, geometry

I do not understand how is $r^2 = x^2+y^2+z^2$ in spherical coordinate system. Can anybody give a simple derivation? I need to understand this in order to understand the Lorentz transformation.

Comment: This is simply Pythagoras' theorem in 3 dimensions. In 2D you're presumably used to the equation for the total distance if you move a distance $x$ then a distance $y$: $d^2 = x^2 + y^2$. The equation you quote simply extends this into 3D.

Comment: $r$ is not a derived quantity but an independent coordinate in spherical coordinates. Given $r$ and two angles, then $x$, $y$ and $z$ are derived.

Answer (score 3):

Use Pythagoreas' theorem twice: the projection of $r=(x,y,z)$ onto the XY-plane has the length $d=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$ and is orthogonal to the $z$-component of $r$. Hence we can use the theorem again and get $|r|=\sqrt{d^2+z^2}=\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}$.

Answer (score 1):

In spherical coordinates you might have the position vector as

$$ \vec{r} = (x,y,z) = \begin{pmatrix} r \cos \varphi \cos\psi \\ r \sin \psi \\  -r \sin\varphi \cos\psi \end{pmatrix} $$

Now with some trigonometry you have

$$ x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = (r \cos \varphi \cos\psi)^2 + (r \sin \psi)^2 + (r \sin\varphi \cos\psi)^2 = \\ ( r^2 \cos^2\varphi + r^2 \sin^2\varphi ) \cos^2\psi + r^2 \sin^2 \psi = \\
r^2 \cos^2\psi + r^2 \sin^2 \psi = r^2 $$